# Jpa prepersist callback not called on parent

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

My code

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class SiteMessage implements Identifiable{
    @PrePersist
    public void onCreate1(){
        System.out.println("Executed onCreate1");
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "feedback")
public class Feedback extends SiteMessage {
    @PrePersist
    public void onCreate2(){
        System.out.println("Executed onCreate2");
    }
}
```

When i save Feedback entity i expect that i will see: Executed onCreate1 and Executed onCreate2, but i've seen only Executed onCreate2

I use eclipselink v2.5.2

Comment: Are both table records being inserted? OTOH if I was persist an instance of a subclass then I'd expect the `@PrePersist` method of this subclass be called but not the superclass'. After all the subclass is a full entity that will be persisted into two tables but still a single object.

Comment: I have a date field in my parent class, and i want set current time on create a new record in database

Comment: Does it work if you use joined inheritance instead?

Comment: Yes. It works when i use joined inheritance type. I've created a test repo https://github.com/SunPj/eclipselink-h2-jpa/tree/master

Answer (score 8):

The Book Mastering the Java persistence API notes the following:

> Inheriting Callback Methods
>
> Callback methods may occur on any entity or mapped superclass, be it
>   abstract or concrete. The rule is fairly simple. **It is that every
>   callback method for a given event type will be invoked in the order
>   according to its place in the hierarchy, most general classes first.**
>   Thus, if in our Employee hierarchy that we saw in Figure 10-10 the
>   Employee class contains a PrePersist callback method named
>   checkName(), and FullTimeEmployee also contains a PrePersist callback
>   method named verifyPension(), when the PrePersist event occurs, the
>   checkName() method will get invoked, followed by the verifyPension()
>   method.

Therefore if everything else in your original code was correct you should expect to see both onCreateOne() and onCreateTwo() called and in that order.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class SiteMessage implements Identifiable{
    @PrePersist
    public void onCreateOne(){
        System.out.println("Executed onCreate1"); //executes first
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "feedback")
public class Feedback extends SiteMessage {
    @PrePersist
    public void onCreateTwo(){
        System.out.println("Executed onCreate2"); //executes second
    }
}
```

It goes on to note the following so you should be able to set things up exactly as required.

> We could also have a method on the CompanyEmployee mapped superclass
>   that we want to apply to all the entities that subclassed it. If we
>   add a PrePersist method named checkVacation() that verifies that the
>   vacation carryover is less than a certain amount, it will be executed
>   after checkName() and before verifyPension(). It gets more interesting
>   if we define a checkVacation() method on the PartTimeEmployee class
>   because part-time employees don’t get as much vacation. **Annotating the
>   overridden method with PrePersist would cause the
>   PartTimeEmployee.checkVacation() method to be invoked instead of the
>   one in CompanyEmployee**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class SiteMessage implements Identifiable{
    @PrePersist
    public void onCreate(){
        System.out.println("Executed onCreate1"); //will not execute
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "feedback")
public class Feedback extends SiteMessage {
    @PrePersist
    public void onCreate(){
        System.out.println("Executed onCreate2"); //will execute
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't than me need. I need only one callback in my parent class, but it doesn't work (even if i remove callback from child class).

Comment: The first one isn't work that i expect. Method onCreateOne() hasn't  executed. I've only seen "Executed onCreate2"

Comment: I've made test project to show that PreCreate doesn't work.
https://github.com/SunPj/eclipselink-h2-jpa/tree/master

Comment: When i changed eclipselink to hibernate all work fine. I think it's a bug

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Annotation "@MappedSuperClass" on the Base entity (Parent).
As I can show:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Base implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @PastOrPresent
    private OffsetDateTime createdAt;

    @PastOrPresent
    private OffsetDateTime updatedAt;

    //get/set here

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        createdAt = OffsetDateTime.now();
        updatedAt = OffsetDateTime.now();
    }

}
```

Inner class:

```
@Entity
@HasExtendedValidator
public class Settings extends Base implements Serializable  {
..
}
```

Work like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

According to the answers of @Alan Hay and @Dante, it seems to work if the parent class is annotated with @MappedSuperclass. I did not verify this by myself, however.

In my case, I could not use @MappedSuperclass as I still wanted to use the superclass as an @Entity and the @Entity annotation does not work together with @MappedSuperclass.

At least with the current Hibernate Version, superclasses of the parent class without @MappedSuperclass do not get registered for callbacks in Hibernate's internal event callbackRegistry so that's why it is not working in this case.
There is another option that works:

Register @EntityListeners on the parent @Entity class and it will get triggered for all subclasses too. E.g:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@EntityListeners(MyListener.class)
public class SiteMessage implements Identifiable{
   
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "feedback")
public class Feedback extends SiteMessage {
   
}

class MyListener{

    @PrePersist
    public void onCreate(SiteMessage o) {
        System.out.println("Executed onCreate")
    }
}
```

If you can't make MyListener generic enough to support all your subclasses, create specific Listeners (e.g. MyListener2 ) for those too and register them on the subclasses. Listeners are additive unless sublasses are annotated with @ExcludeSuperclassListeners