# @PrePersist with entity inheritance in JPA with hibernate provider

Tags: hibernate, jpa

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.Joined)
public class SiteMessage implements Identifiable{
    private String uid;
    @PrePersist
    public void onCreate(){
        uid = "12344"; // Actually we generates new value here
        System.out.println("Executed onCreate1");
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "feedback")
public class Feedback extends SiteMessage {
    @PrePersist
    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        System.out.println("Executed onCreate2");
    }
}
```

When i save SiteMessage entity then i see: Executed onCreate1. When i try to save the Feedback entity, onCreate() method of Feedback or SiteMessage  is not getting executed.

If I store/persist instances of the Base class to the database, everything works fine. The dates are getting updated. But now, if I want to persist a child instance, the database throws the following exception:

**org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Column 'uid' cannot be null**

So, in my opinion, this is caused because in Child the method "@PrePersist protected void updateDates()" is not called/invoked before persisting the instances to the database.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks similar to the question here (in fact you are both using the same entities!): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26060940/jpa-prepersist-callback-not-called-on-parent/26063003#26063003 In line with my answer to that question, this should work. The person who asked that question noted that it worked with Hibernate but not EclipseLink...

Comment: Thanks Alan, will check and let u know...