# Persist "computed" field in JPA (plus Jackson) on Spring Boot application

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, jackson

I have a JPA entity that looks like:

```
public final class Item implements Serializable {
  @Column(name = "col1")
  private String col1;

  @Column(name = "col2")
  @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
  private String col2;

  @Column(name = "col3")
  private String col3;

  Item() { }

  public Item(String col1, String col2) {
    this.col1 = col1;
    this.col2 = col2;
    col3 = col1 + col2 + "some other stuff";
  }

  // getters, equals, hashCode and toString
}
```

I would like to be able to persist `col3`. I'm sending a request via POST that looks like:

```
{
  "col1": "abc",
  "col2": "def"
}
```

...and I'm receiving something like this:

```
[
    {
        "createdAt": "2017-09-07T19:18:17.04-04:00",
        "updatedAt": "2017-09-07T19:18:17.04-04:00",
        "id": "015e5ea3-0ad0-4703-af04-c0a3d46aa836",
        "col1": "abc",
        "col3": null
    }
]
```

Eventually, `col3` is not being persisted in the database. I don't have any setters.

Is there any way to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

The accepted solution is the "less intrusive" one. The proposed one from Jarrod Roberson also works flawlessly. And eventually, you can achieve the same by using a setter on `col2` and set the value of `col3` there — but I dislike this one...although a personal preference.

Comment: There is a reason why fields like `col3` are called computed, you can always "compute" them from other fields. Can you provide a valid use case and why you can't solve this with a simple getter?
Something like: `public String getCol3() { col1 + col2 + "some other stuff" }` and remove the `col3` property.

Comment: @vl4d1m1r4 I had it like that until the point "it was required to persist this value" also in the database. I was returning it in a getter before. The field is actually made out of `col2` only: the last 3 characters (and it never changes). I can actually modify the user-agent(s) to send it also, but it makes no sense since I have the whole data already and I can split it and take the required piece(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is an accepted answer it seems overly complex and requires the removal of the default constructor which is in violation of the JPA spec.

**Section 2.1**

> The entity class must have a no-arg constructor. The entity class may
>   have other constructors as well. The no-arg constructor must be public
>   or protected.

There is no need to get Jackson involved here. You can simply use a JPA pre-persist listener to ensure col3 is set before the flush operation

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html

```
public final class Item implements Serializable {
  @Column(name = "col1")
  private String col1;

  @Column(name = "col2")
  @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
  private String col2;

  @Column(name = "col3")
  private String col3;

  Item() { }

  @PrePersist
  public void updateCol3(){
      col3 = col1 + col2;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would need to check this approach also. The only reason I can think it's not going to work is because there is a quite long hierarchy this class hangs off from. There is already an existent `@PrePersist` in a "base" class, although calling `super` first and then this one might do the trick. That's possible but I don't know if that can have "side effects". Will update it later on when I'm able to test it. Thanks for the info!

Comment: JPA Listeners will execute in a consistent order across a class hierarchy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26063003/1356423

Answer (score 2):

The reason why this is not persisted is because the constructor you have provided with `col1` and `col2` properties is never really called. When spring does the mapping (with help of jackson) from the JSON you send to the server it uses the default constructor to create the object and then calls the setters(sometimes through reflection) to set the values. Therefore the value that is stored in the db for `col3` is always null. See Jarrod Roberson's answer how to solve it :).

Comment: You are right, I was initially "inclined" to put a setter for `col2` (and compute `col3` there) since that's the only way I make it work initially...but I liked Jarrod Roberson answer better. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

#### What you are looking for is [`@JsonCreator`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html) it is used like this:

```
@JsonCreator()
public Item(@JsonProperty("col1") String col1, @JsonProperty("col2") String col2) {
  this.col1 = col1;
  this.col2 = col2;
  this.col3 = col1 + col2 + "some other stuff";
}
```

Then **remove** the default no-args constructor and Jackson will use this one and what you want will happen *auto-magically*.

> This is a very old
>   [feature](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureCreators) back from
>   the `1.x` era. You can also annotate a `static` *Factory Method*
>   instead and make the constructor `private` for cases where you need to
>   use more complicated logic like something that is constructed with a
>   *Builder Pattern*.

Here is an example:

```
@JsonCreator()
public static Item construct(@JsonProperty("col1") String col1, @JsonProperty("col2") String col2) {
  return new Item(col1, col2, col1 + col2 + "some other stuff");
}

private Item(final String col1, final String col2, final String col3) {
  this.col1 = col1;
  this.col2 = col2;
  this.col3 = col3;
}
```

Comment: This is cool. I've used `@JsonCreator` before but it didn't occur me to use here. One thing: I had to keep the default constructor; looks like the way the system is using this entity already (it's actually more complex since it's inside a collection and wrapped in a different object also). Not sure though. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I think JPA/Hibernate is what is causing you to have to keep the default constructor. JPA/Hibernate is crippling to actual medium/large scale projects. Ugh!